# ADO code no longer performing copy/paste after changing field to a drop down menu

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado, ms-access-2013

I am not sure as to the best way to describe this problem to make it clear to you.  I have recently changed a field on a form which previously was a standard field but for the sake of user friendliness and data quality control, has now become a drop down field linked to a table and therefore provides a drop down list when the user is to enter data (instead of typing).

The issue encounterd is as follows:

This field, upon entering a value (in this case the name of a team (below listed as txtTeam) triggers an after update event so that using ADO code takes the team name, references it to an underlying team table and then copies corresponding values into the fields: "txtCity", "txtCountry", "txtCAP", "txtOfficialTeamName", ect (see below)

Unfortunately, once i changed the team field to a list field linked to the table, the If statement which I flagged below with (*** HERE IS MY PROBLEM - ...) is no longer valid and unfortunately the ADO copy/paste code no longer works.

**Note: When going into the VBA editor and hovering my mouse over "Team_name" and "txtTEam" the following result appears showing me that the issue is directly linked to the fact that I have converted this field to a drop down field.

Team_name = Operational Excellence                 (the actual name of the team selected)
txtTEam = '71'                     (the ID number of the team "Operational Excellence" on the underlying table

I hope someone can help me with this because this form is really useful for me an without this code, it loses alot.
Thanks,
A

```
   Dim rstTEAM As New ADODB.Recordset

    rstTEAM.Open "tblTeams", CurrentProject.Connection, _
                adOpenForwardOnly



    Do Until rstTEAM.EOF
        If rstTEAM!Team_name = txtTEam Then  (*** HERE IS MY PROBLEM- this statement is no longer TRUE)
            txtCity = rstTEAM!City
            txtCountry = rstTEAM!Country
            txtCAP = rstTEAM!CAP
            txtOfficialTeamName = rstTEAM!Official_Team_Name
            txtStreet = rstTEAM!Street
            txtDivision = rstTEAM!Division
            txtNumerotel.SetFocus
            blnAggiunto = True
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rstTEAM.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop

    rstTEAM.Close
    Set rstTEAM = Nothing
```

Comment: PS- I also tried substituting the field name "Team_name" with "ID" thinking that perhaps the value is now viewed by the code as the underlying ID number and not the text but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you are using a listbox, you need to reference the control properly.  I assume you are not allowing multi-select, so you should reference as follows (assuming the key is Col 0, else use 1 or 2...:

```
If rstTEAM!Team_name = Me.txtTEam.Column(0) Then
```

If allowing multi-select, you would use something like:

```
Dim varItem As Variant
For Each varItem In Me.txtTEam.ItemsSelected
    strSQL = strSQL & Me.txtTEam.Column(0, varItem)
Next varItem
```

Comment: thanks Wayne..  i will put that in my library..  btw- when i went to work i found out from a colleague another way to resolve this issue is the following

Comment: If rstTEAM!Team_name = Me.txtTEam.text Then

Comment: My colleague was nice enought to explain to me as to why this is the case as well..   Productive day!